# Can I pass an argument as ?xxx=arg

Tags: views

In Drupal 7, on the home page /home, I have a list of News items in the left column, and want to click on one of the News items in the list, and have the full article for that item show in the right column of the page.

Is there a way to pass an argument that doesn't change the page, like /home?xxx=arg   Everything I read talks about passing arguments in ways that change the page path (i.e., home/news1, or home/news2).

Answer (score 1):

As long as you have something (a custom module, for example) looking for the arguments, yes, you can pass as many arguments as you want.

Depending on the size of the articles, however, instead of requiring a page refresh, I would suggest either an AJAX call (more complicated) or using jQuery (less complicated) to hide the content, and simply show it on demand. If the articles are large though, the jQuery option would be cumbersome and slow the page, since it would load all of the material at page load.

Answer (score 0):

if you are showing news items using block or view than you can do it like this

firstly go to news item block/view then make settings of news item .

and change it as given in below screenshot

[image: screenshot]

may this will help you.

Comment: Thank you for that.  I have tried this but "arg" in xxx=arg needs to be node id.  But mostly I don't know how to READ the argument that is passed this way in the receiving view!  And does it make a difference if the receiving view is in a panel or a block?  Mine is a panel view.